# h2o import table issue with SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, h2o

When trying to connect H2O to SQL Server 2016 to import a table, H2O returns a SQL Exception relating to FETCH Statement.

Environment:

- Ubuntu VM running H2O Version 3.22.0.2
- Windows instance with SQL Server 2016

JDBC Driver/s tested: MSSQL-jdbc-7 , MSSQL-jdbc-6.2.1 and sqljdbc4

```
ERROR MESSAGE: SQLException: Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH 
statement. Failed to connect and read from SQL database with connection_url: 
jdbc:sqlserver://<IP_ADDRESS>:1433;databaseName=DataStage;
```

Any ideas on what can be done to fix this?

Edit: Query used:

```
importSqlTable {"connection_url":"jdbc:sqlserver://<IP_ADDRESS>:1433;databaseName=DataStage;","table":"dbo.TestTable","columns":"","username":"xxxx","password":"XXXX"}
```

Edit 2: this is a clean install of H2O, so if there is any extra configuration that is meant to be done other than adding the driver/s to the class path, pointing me to the relevant documentation would be appreciated.

Edit 3: I've used a db tool (DBVisualiser) on the Ubuntu instance with the MSSQL-7 driver to confirm that the VM can connect to the SQL server, whilst H20 can't connect.

Comment: @MitchWheat - updated with the query used.

Comment: What have you done in configuring the SQL Server? As I think the problem might not be with H2O, it might be having issues connecting to SQL Server...

Comment: @Birel - SQL server has been configured for remote connections, and i've tested that the Ubuntu VM can connect to the SQL Server instance via a DB tool.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bug to me. Do you happen to have the H2O log? It should have the full exception which could tell us what is wrong.

Please file a jira here: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa

We will look into it. Thank you for reporting this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the issue. We will look into it.

In the meantime, there is a workaround available (in R/Python), unfortunately, it doesn't apply to Flow.

In R/Python you can use parameter fetch_mode = "SINGLE" which will disable distributed import and enable compatibility mode. In compatibility mode, any JDBC drive should work just fine as we do not rely on database specific SQL constructs. 

Please refer to our documentation: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/reference/h2o.import_sql_table.html

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same problem. Ran a SQL Server Profiler to see what exactly H2O is trying to do. When you send a Table Parameter it ignores whatever you sent in select_query and it does this:

SELECT * FROM testTable FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY

The funny thing is that it doesn't validate the Table parameter in any way, so you can just initiate a comment after the table name:

table = "testTable --"

and it will produce the query below and import the data successfully :)

SELECT * FROM testTable -- FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY